# 401 error of web services

Tags: authentication, webservice-client

I have a web service

```
[authorization]
      [allow users="domain\myaccount, domain\yyy"/]
      [deny users="*"/]
    [/authorization]

[authentication mode="Windows" /]
```

And I have a web client which calls this web sercice

```
[identity impersonate="true" /]
[authentication mode="Windows" /]
```

I use my own domain account (which listed above, domain\myaccount,  to test the client, but I still got 401 error, any idea?

Comment: Have you made any progress yet?

Answer (score 0):

Use Fiddler or another HTTP debugger (e.g. Firebug in FireFox) to look at the full header.  It will send back the kind of authentication it can handle -- perhaps you aren't sending the credentials in a way that is acceptable to the service.

Answer (score 0):

don't you mean deny '?' not deny *

I was always taught that a deny is stronger than an allow so deny * would deny all even those that were given permission.

I would say you are deny all even those you have given permission to.